# Request to web app on Azure from Android app return 400 bad request

Tags: android, .net, azure, adal

I have a web app (.NET) deployed on Azure. I want to be able to send http requests from an Android app to that app on Azure.

When trying to access one of the endpoints from a browser, I am redirected to a login page (Azure kind login page). After I enter my credentials, I am redirected to the right page and the Json file I wanted to get is displayed so I guess my web app is working.

From my Android application, to handle the authentication part, I use the ADAL library. I have registered a native app on Azure and I am able to authenticate and get a token.

But then when I try to send a request to my web app, putting the token in the header (Authorization: Bearer eyJ0...), **I always get a 400 Bad Request response.**

My native app has access to my web app on Azure (I setup the permissions on the Azure portal), and when I run my web app locally I can successfully send requests from my Android app.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See if this demo project sheds some light: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Android-AzureActiveDirectory

Comment: You may also want to check out this blog post/article: http://chrisrisner.com/Accessing-Resources-Secured-by-Azure-Active-Directory-with-iOS-and-Android